# How to convert Mac's DMG default icon to customized icon using NetBeans?

Tags: java, macos, swing, netbeans

I am developing a Mac application using Java swing and NetBeans, now when the build is taken and converted into a DMG bundle, only the default bundle icon is displayed (ie the Java logo). Now I want a customized icon to be placed instead of the default icon (Java logo). Can anyone help me to replace the default Java icon with my customized icon?

Answer (score 0):

After a deep search, I have found the solution.

1. Create a directory name "*package*" and inside create another directory name "*windows*" (in case if it is Windows platform). In my case, it was Mac so i created "*macosx*".
2. Place that icon file inside that windows/macosx folder. Finally, it will look like this src\project\package\windows and
   src\project\package\macosx (for mac).

Now, goto Tools ---> Options. Choose Java and under that ant tab click on *Add Directory* and give your project source path eg: *projectFolder\src*

Clear and Build your project, you will be done..!